# Fetch data without page redirect

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have three pages. say page1.php , page2.php, page3.php.

I make an ajax request to page2 from page1 to retrieve some data say First_Name...

I need to fetch Last_Name from page3, and return that to either page1 or to page1 via page2...

How is that to be done...??? Tried calling a function in page3 from page2... but that does

not seem to work.................

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: Why not make two AJAX requests or include page3 in page2 if the request is made using AJAX?

Comment: @polarblau: I need to use page3 several times.. including it in page2 won't be efficient...

Comment: @Pekka: I get username and password in page1. Send an jquery ui ajax request and check if they are correct. If correct, I need to visit another page and pull some data from there.. This is to be done without page refresh...

Comment: Yep, that would be two AJAX requests in my book.

Comment: @polarblau: I  get username and password in page1. Send an jquery ui ajax request and check if they are correct. If correct, I need to visit another page and pull some data from there.. This is to be done without page refresh...

Comment: The code to check the username/password and the code that pulls data from "visit another page" can be in the same file. Being in the same file doesn't mean both pieces of code run every time. Put them in two different functions and call the appropriate function depending on which AJAX request you made ($_GET). There is no concept of "pages" here, only requests and responses. Change how you are thinking about it.

Comment: @Kut if PHP have some sort of Session to store data across pages, in `page3` store the data in Session then on consequent calls return the value from Session so it's as efficient as possible..

Comment: You need to send 1 request to Page 2 for fetching First Name..after you receive that response you need to send another request to page3 for Last Name.....

Comment: Thanx every one...!!! all of ur responses vr cumulatively similar to kishan's.. working without probs..Thannx every1...

Comment: Someone invented commas, use them. Please.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Dan Grossman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280598/dan-grossman) , you need a design change to do the above in much better way.

One or multiple classes, with different functions to accomplish the above is the better approach than to think of pages. I don't see the need why you need to "visit another page" to pull some more data, if this data is available on the server?